# Why adding dependency causes error in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on a web app i am implementing routes , i have added route CDN and when i added `ngRoute` as a dependency to myApp it is not working now.Before adding ngRoute viewproducts was working fine but now what i am seeing is :
`{{product.name}} {{product.company}}` and not the actual values.

**Module CODE :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/addproduct', {
                  templateUrl:'addproduct.html',
                  controller:'myController'
             })
});
```

**Controller CODE :**

```
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.insertData = function(){
        $http.post("addProduct.php",{'pname': $scope.productname,'company': $scope.company,'price': $scope.price,'quantity':$scope.quantity})
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){

           $scope.successMessage = "Inserted Successfuly!"; 
        });
    }

});
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700, 600,500,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="angularkhan.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="nav-trigger"><span></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="side-nav">
            <div class="logo">
                <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            <span>Users</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="addproduct.html">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            <span>Add Product</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="viewproducts.html">

                            <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <span>View Products</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></span>
                            <span>Analytics</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt"></i></span>
                            <span>Payments</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="title">
                Add Product
            </div>

            <div class="main" ng-view> 

                <form style="padding:10px">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ProductName">Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Name" ng-model="productname">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="company">Company </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="company" ng-model="company">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="company">Price </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="price" ng-model="price">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="company">Quantity </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="quantity" ng-model="quantity">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="insertData()">Submit</button>
                      <h1>{{successMessage}}</h1>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you have add the html as well? And is there some kind of error in the console?

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be redifining your module.
Do you have the following code elsewhere in your project?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [...]);
```

If you do, the second module call with brackets would redefine the existing module. Try adding the ngRoute dependency to the first module definition and remove the brackets of the one in config. It should then look like below.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of your scripts matters! The file where you create your angular module app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

This file should be after the `angular-route` file.

Fixed:

```
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="angularkhan.js"></script>
```

Comment: i got the view which is working fine now but WHEN i click ADD PRODUCT it get's hanged 
CODE {myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/viewproduct',{
                     templateUrl: 'viewproducts.html',
                     controller: 'getController'
        }).
        when('/addproduct',{
                    templateUrl: 'addproduct.html',
                    controller: 'myController'
        })
});} and Console gives this error (RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded)